# Atom Beautify plugin breaks my React html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, atom-editor, atom-beautify

When I am just typing this file, code works.
When using Beautify plugin for Atom, code doesn't work.

I am trying to compare those files, but anyway cannot find my mistake.

Where can be a problem? May be Beautify blocks transpiler or something?

```html
//This is unstyled and working version.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>

  <title>React components</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='react-container'></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
              var MyComponent = React.createClass({
                  render() {
                      return <div>
                          <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
                          <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                      </div>
                  }
              })
          ReactDOM.render(<div>
            <MyComponent text ="Hello World">My</MyComponent>
          <MyComponent text ="Hello World">Name is</MyComponent>
          <MyComponent text ="Hello World">Anatoly</MyComponent></div>,
        document.getElementById('react-container'))
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>

  <title>React components</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='react-container'></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({ render() { return
    <div>
      <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
      <p>{this.props.children}</p>
    </div>
    } }) ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <MyComponent text="Hello World">My</MyComponent>
      <MyComponent text="Hello World">Name is</MyComponent>
      <MyComponent text="Hello World">Anatoly</MyComponent>
    </div>, document.getElementById('react-container'))
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Gist to that files](https://gist.github.com/akhalizev/4a8670d895635cb9d935ed0507a1dbeb)

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Ugh... you should really learn about semicolons and how they are used. Close your statements. `var variable = 'value';` <-- semicolon. use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: issue Screenshot]

```
 <script type="text/babel">
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({ render() { return <div>
      <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
      <p>{this.props.children}</p>
    </div>
    } }) 
    ReactDOM.render(<div>
      <MyComponent text="Hello World">My</MyComponent>
      <MyComponent text="Hello World">Name is</MyComponent>
      <MyComponent text="Hello World">Anatoly</MyComponent>
    </div>, document.getElementById('react-container'))
  </script>
```

Comment: Seems correct. You can't have a newline directly after return. The second red box should not be causing any problems (newline after function call parenthesis is ok).

Comment: Finally I moved React.DOM.render on a new line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, put `ReactDOM.render` onto a new line.

Comment: Hey there. The way to mark an answer as useful is to mark it as accepted, like you already did. Please do not duplicate the answer.